# How to get latest - 2 table name from sas library?

Tags: sas

I dont have knowledge in sas , i have got this task to complete

there was 3 scenario

1. get the lastest table from the library , which im getting with this query

   ```
   proc sql outobs=1;
    select memname 
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = KALP51' and memname like 'RM_RV_MONTHWISE_%_MAIN'
     order by input (scan (memname, -2,'_'), monyy7.) desc;
     quit;
   ```

2 Get latest - 1 table from the library , which im getting with this query

```
proc sql outobs=1;
select memname 
from dictionary.tables
where libname = KALP51' and memname like 'RM_RV_MONTHWISE_%_MAIN'
having input(scan (memname, -2, '_'), monyy7.) < max(input(scan (memname, -2, '_'), monyy7.))
 order by input (scan (memname, -2,'_'), monyy7.) desc;
 quit;
```

Both of this query was provided on SO itslef, i later understand it little bit and adjusted accrding to my need

now the third scerio is to get latest - 2 table from the library , which i dont know how can i get

i know by adding outobs = 2 will give me the -2 table in the seond row

with this query

```
proc sql outobs=2;
    select memname 
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = KALP51' and memname like 'RM_RV_MONTHWISE_%_MAIN'
    having input(scan (memname, -2, '_'), monyy7.) < max(input(scan (memname, -2, '_'), monyy7.))
     order by input (scan (memname, -2,'_'), monyy7.) desc;
     quit;
```

but i only want that specific table and no two of them

can anyone help me out here ?

Edit 1 :-Example output

Scenario 1 :- `KALP51.RM_RV_MONTHWISE_SEP23_MA`IN // getting this output

Scenario 2 :- `KALP51.RM_RV_MONTHWISE_AUG23_MAIN` // getting this output

Scenario 3 :- `KALP51.RM_RV_MONTHWISE_JUL23_MAIN` // Expected Output

Please note it dosent means there will always be a previous month table available for

if lastest table is  `KALP51.RM_RV_MONTHWISE_SEP23_MAIN` it can be possible that latest -1 can give me `KALP51.RM_RV_MONTHWISE_JUL23_MAIN` , because `KALP51.RM_RV_MONTHWISE_AUG23_MAIN` is simply not there

same with scenario 3

its possible that i cant get alwasy Month -1 table , thats why i said Latest -1 and Latest -2

Comment: What do you mean by 'latest'? Seems like you're defining latest from a data set name suffix?

Comment: i mean by the date here '%' there are date eg MonYY  JUN23 or SEP23 this way, so by latest i mean by the date section in between the table name

Comment: @PeterClemmensen Please check Edit 1 in the question

Comment: What do the strings in the name mean?  Is SEP23 the 23rd of September?  What year?  Or  does it mean September in some year 23?  Is that supposed to be the year 2023?

Comment: Yes correct its September 2023

Answer (score 0):

First step is to get the dates OUT OF THE NAME and into an actual variable.

The expression you are using with LIKE is not precise enough since it will match names with any character where you have the underscores (single character wildcard).  Perhaps your real database does not have any other datasets that match the broader pattern you are using?  You can use an escape character to convert the underscores to literal characters instead.

```
 memname like 'RM^_RV^_MONTHWISE^_%^_MAIN' escape '^'
```

But it is probably just easier to skip the like and do the pattern match with other functions.

It is probably a little faster to just query DICTIONARY.MEMBERS since you only appear to need the dataset name and not the extra information like number of variables or number of observations that DICTIONARY.TABLES would have to calculate.

You could make a dataset:

```
proc sql ;
  create table month_names as
  select libname,memname
       , input(scan(memname,-2,'_'),?monyy7.) as date format=yymm7.
  from dictionary.members
  where libname = 'KALP51'
    and type='DATA'
    and memname eqt 'RM_RV_MONTHWISE_'
    and scan(memname,-1,'_') = 'MAIN'
  order by date desc 
 ;
quit;
```

And then work from that.

But If you just need the latest 2 or three dataset names you could just put them into macro variables.

If you really just need the names of the most recent month/dates dataset you could write them directly to macro variables.  It is not clear to me if you need the two most "recent" names or three.  But you might as well make three.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select memname into :ds1-:ds3
  from dictionary.members
  where libname = 'KALP51'
    and type='DATA'
    and memname eqt 'RM_RV_MONTHWISE_'
    and scan(memname,-1,'_') = 'MAIN'
  order by input(scan(memname,-2,'_'),?monyy7.) desc 
 ;
quit;
```

So &DS1 should have the name of the most recent (most recently named) dataset. &DS2 the one before that. &DS3 the one before that.

The automatic macro variable SQLOBS will let you know how many it was able to find.

You could also pull out the date values into another set of macro variables if you want to be sure what month the name represents.

```
  select memname 
       , input(scan(memname,-2,'_'),?monyy7.) as date format=yymm7.
    into :ds1-:ds3
       , :month1-:month3
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, you can list the tables from the newest to the oldest with a `sql` query. To that query you can add an `into` clause, which writes the first value to a macro variable, so this prints the name of the most recent file to the log.

```
proc sql;
   select memname
   into :last_memname
   from dictionary.tables
   where libname = KALP51' and memname like 'RM_RV_MONTHWISE_%_MAIN'
   order by input (scan (memname, -2,'_'), monyy7.) desc;
quit;
%put NOTE: the last RM_RV_MONTHWISE_..._MAIN -member of KALP51 was & last_memname;
```

Adding `separated by` to the `into` -clause, you get all the files of the given template in a list. Let us use the pipe symbol as separator, then you can use the macro-code variant `%scan` of `scan` to extract the forelast and last dataset from the macrovariable.

Suppose you want to use the two most recent tables as input to a data step, then this is the solution:

```
proc sql noprint;
   select memname
   into : main_list separated by '|'
   from dictionary.tables
   where libname = KALP51' and memname like 'RM_RV_MONTHWISE_%_MAIN'
   order by input (scan (memname, -2,'_'), monyy7.);
quit;
data FORELAST_AND_LAST_MAIN;
   set %scan(&main_list, -2, |) %scan(&main_list, -1, |);
run;
```